# list index out of range while reading csv python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to find few items from a CSV file when I run the code sometimes it works but sometimes it produces error list index out of range

```
def find_check_in(name,date):
    x = 0
    f = open('employee.csv','r')

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        id = row[0]
        dt = row[1]
        v  = row[2]
        a = datetime.strptime(dt,"%Y-%m-%d")
        if v == "Check-In" and id=="person":
            x = 1

    f.close()            
    return x
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 51, in 
>       x=find_check_in(name,date)
>
> File "", line 21, in find_check_in
>       id = row[0]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This seems like a case where there are random blank lines in your csv file before your end of file. a single if(row) check might do the trick

Comment: you can check his answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335829/8824174

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file contains blank lines, resulting in `row` becoming an empty list, in which case there is no index 0, hence the error. Make sure your input CSV has no blank line, or add a condition to process the row only if it isn't empty:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        # the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like reader is returning a row with no elements. Does your data contain any such rows? Or perhaps you need to use the `newline=''` argument to `reader`?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader